# Login to Google using windows form c#

Tags: c#, api, google-drive-api, windowsformshost

Hi everyone I have a problem I wanna create app for generate account google drive with api google drive and I don't know how can I login with account from application not navigator C# windows form.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSgMu.png)

and how can i edit this credential with exist user

Comment: Have you read the [guides](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)?

Comment: @BiesiGrr yes but i dont understand

Comment: I want a code that will connect me to google, for example, I just give it my email and password and he logs in and gives me a token

Comment: Give us your best shot. What have you tried?

Comment: I use credentials and put in them GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker........ but he send me to navigator to give him mail and pass and authorisation

Comment: i don't wanna this method of work i wanna create form to login and us class from api google or any other place to logs in and give me what i want

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Show us what you have tried.  You cant create a form to login to Google you need to go though googles oauth server they create the form.

Comment: ok i will do that thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I have used those steps and worked perfectly for me. You don't have a choice than to be redirected to the Google authentication page.
After entering your Google credentials, you are redirected back to the your site.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are trying to use [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) from a console application. Or for that matter a fully desktop application.

Take one thing in consideration, if you don't use [Service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) **you must let the user authenticate to google** and allow your application to work in his/her behalf. There is **no way around this**.

What you can do is after the user has already signed in, is to **save the tokens and [refresh them](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.)** whenever necessary.

Of course OAuth may be complicated, but **you use the [.NET library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)** everything will be managed for you. And you can look at **a real example in the [.NET Drive Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)**